# How can I use outliner dots(?? I don't know it's name)?

Tags: outliner

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z11Sv_kkoUs

In this video, I saw dots which can make me switch object to other not in object mode.

But I don't know how can I activate the dots.

Please let me know that.

I use 2.90.1 ver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Mode toggling* is a [2.91 feature](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.91/User_Interface). You need to update your Blender version.

> Move mode toggling to the left column. When in non-object modes, icon buttons are shown in the left column for toggling modes. Clicking a dot icon will switch that object to become the new active object, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click adds the object into the current mode. ([2110af20f5](http://developer.blender.org/rB2110af20f5e6))

Comment: thank you very much